# Why am I getting "Structure needs cleaning" message on Ceph with Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ceph

Sorry to ask this, I am relatively new in Kubernetes and Ceph, only have a little idea about this.

I have setup Kubernetes and Ceph using this tutorial(http://tutorial.kubernetes.noverit.com/content/ceph.html)

I had set up my cluster like this:

1 Kube-Master and 2 worker Nodes(this acts ceph monitor with 2 OSD in each)
The ceph-deploy I used to setup ceph cluster is in the Kube-master.

Everything is working fine, I installed my sample web application(deployment)  with 5 replicas, which will create a file when the rest API is hit. The file is getting copied to every node.

But after 10 min, I created one more file using the API, but when I try to list(ls -l) I am getting the following error:

For node1:

```
ls: cannot access 'previousFile.txt': Structure needs cleaning
previousFile.txt  newFile.txt
```

For node2:

```
previousFile.txt
```

For node2 the new file is not created

What might be the issue? I have tried many times still same error pop up.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This totally looks like your filesystem got corrupted. Things to check:

- `$ kubectl logs <ceph-pod1>`
- `$ kubectl logs <ceph-pod2>`
- `$ kubectl describe deployment <ceph-deployment>` # did any of the pods restart?

Some info about the error message [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330742/cannot-remove-file-structure-needs-cleaning).

Depending on what you have you might need to start from scratch. Or you can take a look a [recovering data](https://ceph.com/planet/recovering-data-from-a-rbd-image/) in Ceph, but may not work if you don't have a snap.

Running Ceph on Kubernetes can be very tricky because any start/restart for a specific node starting on a different Kubernetes node might corrupt the data, so you need to make sure that part is pretty solid possibly using [Node Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/) or running Ceph pods on specific Kubernetes nodes with [labels](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/).

Comment: I am trying to write data in Ceph RBD. In kuberetes official documentation states write to multiple nodes are not supported for RBD, I think this might be reason for data corruption.